# How to create a PCM wav with mplayer?

Tags: mplayer

I want to reencode a audiobook for my mobile with speexenc. The first step is to reencode the file with mplayer.

```
for i in *.mp3; do
    mplayer -ao pcm:waveheader "$i" -af pan=1:0.5:0.5,resample=22050 -ao pcm:file="$i.wav";
done
```

Is what I found on the internet. But the outfile is not a pcm wav:

```
file *.wav
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, mono 22050 Hz
```

Where a reference wav from xiph.org is pcm.

```
file wb_male.wav 
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 16000 Hz
```

speexenc does encode the last PCM WAV, but does not with the mplayer file. Why not? The does the Audiooutput called "pcm" does not ouput a pcm file? How to Fix it? And is there a easy way to pipe the wav directly to speexenc without a named fifo?

Answer (score 4):

The [MPlayer man page](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.txt) uses this syntax:

```
mplayer -ao pcm:file=test.wav test.avi
```

If you want to do things like limiting sampling rate, you can throw on an `-srate` option (like `-srate 44100` for redbook CD audio).

But, if you have it installed, I'd suggest using `ffmpeg` because it's actually meant for doing these things.

Answer (score 2):

The wav file generated by `mplayer -ao pcm` from an mp3 is in PCM format. It just happens to be floating-point PCM because that's what comes naturally out of the mp3 decoder. `file` should have told you this, but it doesn't know about the floating-point PCM format.

The mp3 decoder produces float and `-ao pcm` just writes whatever format it receives, so you need something between them to change the format: the `af format` filter. For signed 16-bit little-endian (which is what you probably want), `-af format=s16le` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run mplayer with pcm output it tells you the fastest way to do it:

```
Info: Faster dumping is achieved with -benchmark -vc null -vo null -ao pcm:fast
```

so

```
mplayer in.mp3 -benchmark -vc null -vo null -ao pcm:fast:file=out.wav -af format=s16le
```

Result:

```
$ file out.wav
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 48000 Hz
```

Is that good enough? You can use sox or audacity to convert stereo to mono.